# Why isn't safe sync mode enabled by default?

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands

Currently, people need to manually type "save" in the daemon when they want to save the blockchain. Why doesn't the daemon have the option `--db-sync-mode safe` enabled by default? This way new users are less likely to abandon Monero out of frustration if their computer restarts unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly because it's a lot slower, which could cause users to abandon Monero out of frustration if they can't sync in a few days.

There are recent improvements to a "sweet spot", however. See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/65e33b1bc51d6540f23c8de0dbf4826a56549373

Comment: The explanation of those commits is more informative for this question. https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1506#issuecomment-269497360